# Arithmetic Mean Inequality for Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I would like to show that there exists some scalar $\eta>0$ such that
$\eta A^TA \preccurlyeq \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ for any square matrix $A$ with nonnegative eigenvalues that are bounded by 1 $(0\leq \lambda(A)\leq 1)$. $A$ is not necessarily symmetric.
If it helps $A=I-W$ where $W$ is a row stochastic matrix with positive entries.

I tried to rely on the following: for any two PSD matrices $U,V$ it holds that $\sigma(UV)\leq \frac{1}{2}\sigma(U^2+V^2)$ where $\sigma(C)$ represents the singular value of the matrix $C$.
However, $A$ is not symmetric in general.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: notice that $\sigma(UV)\leq \frac{1}{2}\sigma(U^2+V^2)$ is homogenous with all matrix products having degree two but the desired $\eta A^TA \preccurlyeq \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$  has degree 2 on the LHS and degree 1 on the RHS... this creates many problems.  E.g. the claim won't even work when $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 3):

This is not always possible, as $\eta A^TA$ is always positive semidefinite but $\frac12(A+A^T)$ isn't, such as when
$$
A=I-\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&0}=\pmatrix{0&0\\ -1&1}.
$$
By perturbing the $W$ above slightly, you may also obtain a counterexample in which $W$ is entrywise positive, i.e. you may consider
$$
A=I-\pmatrix{1-\epsilon&\epsilon\\ 1-\epsilon&\epsilon}=\pmatrix{\epsilon&-\epsilon\\ \epsilon-1&1-\epsilon}
$$
for some sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edit my question such $W$ has only positive entries. Does it change anything? or you can still think about other counter examples?

Comment: @RegevCohen That doesn't change anything. You can perturb the $A$ in my answer slightly to obtain a counterexample in which $W$ is entrywise positive.